# Actual Java Beginner Tutorial for experience Flash developer

Tags: java, flash

I am looking for a tutorial to teach an experience Flash/Flex developer the java 6! basics, and later on the java Java EE basics, in English or German.

I only found the [Sun Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), but I hope someone knows another good tutorial, for example something with an continuous example and not just a list of features like in the Sun Tutorial. (All other tutorial I found was most with Java 1.4 (or older9 or does contain bad coding practices.)

Does anybody knows such an actual Java 6 tutorial?

Comment: For most of the basics, Java 1.4 and Java 6 are the same.  Java 6 adds some features but everything you learn for Java 1.4 would be useful. As a Flash developer you may be interested in JavaFX.

Comment: There are plenty of Java tutorials for beginners as you say. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+tutorials+for+beginners 718K. I don't know if many experienced developers write tutorials for beginners for free. Possibly because it took them 10+ years to learn what they know and don't feel it can be condensed into a few tutorials. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey : Java 1.4 and Java 5 differs a lot in how is good code written! (Generics and other stuff). The main problem is, that I do not want that my college lerns a bad/old style, and then I have to explain that this is old school.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: may you are right with "it took them 10+ years to learn what they know and don't feel it can be condensed into a few tutorials." - but on the other hand, Stack Overflow works in this way. ;-) And a Google result of 718K+ items does not make it easy to find any good one.

Comment: I have programming Java commercialy for 12 years, so I don't remember what it is like to learn Java, but I think you are making too big a deal of this.  The best thing to do is to get good practice for your self.  You won't be contamined by reading an example without generics.  There is so much to learn which takes time that being picky is just going to slow you down. My advise is don't worry so much, just get on with it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are great websites with tutorials and what not, but if you invested a few dollars in the following book I guarantee you will not regret it.

[http://www.amazon.com/Core-Java-TM-I--Fundamentals-8th/dp/0132354764/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1304069932&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354764)

there is also a second volume,

[http://www.amazon.com/Core-Java-Vol-Advanced-Features/dp/0132354799/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1304070002&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354799)

Comment: yurics: I have found this comment to the book "but the code samples advocate a truly awful programming methodology, where computational engines are intermingled with window system calls". Can you confirm this statement, or is it wrong?

Comment: On rare occasions you will see windows systems calls - however I do not believe the few sections of code which contain this material spoil the book.